# Android onBackPressed() come back to previous Fragment/Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, onbackpressed

I'm using Navigation Drawer in My Project

My Project contains some Fragment Files and also some Activity Files

I just need whatever the file may me `onBackPressed()` it should come back to previous fragment to activity and visa versa

For example:

**START**: `MainActivity > Fragment > Fragment > Activity`

**onBackPressed()**: `Activity > Fragment > Fragment > MainActivity` --- Then a `dialogBox` with Exit or Not

I tried some methods from other StackOverflow Posts, but not a single post worked For me

---

## Tried Example

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you tried addToBackstack method ?

Comment: how to implement that..??? please can you edit the upper code

Comment: Not only this place to edit . It should edit from the begining . Example from coming from Fragment1 to Fragment2 you should to add replace transaction to the backstack.

Comment: can you share your mail ID..?

Comment: You can use http://pastebin.com/ for sharing your code .

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `addToBackStack` when you add/replace/commit the fragment transaction. When you click a link, or a button, or however you're doing your navigation, at that point you need to start a fragment transaction, replacing the existing fragment with whatever your new fragment is. Importantly, you need to `addToBackStack` before you commit the transaction

What that does is add your current fragment to the backstack, so when the user presses the back button in your new fragment, that are taken back to the previous fragment

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new_fragment_class).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

You would not do this in the `onBackPressed` method like you currently are, but when the user clicks something in your nav drawer. So you need a way to catch user clicks on your navigation menu items. For example:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_new:
            //do your add/replace fragment transaction here
            break;
    }    
}
```

Once you have the actual backstack in place (with the above), it looks like your `if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0...` code should work. That would just check whether there are any items in the current backstack, and if not, show a dialog box

EDIT:

Heres an example of how I handle fragment transactions with a nav drawer:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //set initial fragment to 'new' instead
        addFragment(new NewFragment(), true);

        //Set the toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Set navigation drawer
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            //put your alert dialog code here
            //if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) ...
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        // Replace these with your own menu items
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_start:
                addFragment(new StartFragment(), true);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_save:
                addFragment(new SaveFragment(), true);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_raw:
                addFragment(new RawFragment(), true);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_gyroscope:
                addFragment(new GyroscopeFragment(), true);
                break;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean addToBackStack) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to be far more specific about what you did and what didnt work. Update your original with the new code

Comment: see my edit for a working example (you'll need to change variable names etc around to make it work in your case)

Comment: The way you have it set up in your edited code example will create a new fragment (HomeFragment) whenever back is pressed. This is not the behaviour you want because then your back button doesnt function correctly and will just keep reshowing that fragment. Try removing that entire section of code where you create and commit the Home fragment transaction